Analytic geometry problem, can't get same results solving by middle points & slope?
If the symmetry of point $A(-1, 0)$ on the analytical plane with respect to the line $ax+2y-3=0$ is $B(3, -2)$, what is $a$?
Now, when you solve this not by the classical method but by using the product of slopes $=-1$, the correct answer does not come out.
The slope of points $A$ and $B$: $-1/2$. If we arrange the equation, the slope of the equation is $-a/2$.
$(-a/2) (-1/2) = -1$ gives $a = -4$, but the answer is $5$ by finding the midpoints and adding them to the equation. When you type it instead, it comes out $5$. Why didn't doing it from the slope give any results?

when i put middle points (1,-1) okay I get the result, but why does the product of their slopes don't give the same result? by slope, I get a = -4. but when I work with middle points, a =5 and correct answer is given as 5.

A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

I believe i explained clearly. what is the problem?

The problem is that, as I explained in my previous comment, your problem cannot be understood by someone who did not read the title. The title should never be the first sentence of the post.

I edited. I hope I can get an answer now.

In your post, the symbol $a$ means two distinct things.

Yes, you are right, I edited it also.

That problem has no solution. Let $C_a$ be the reflection of $A$ on the line $r_a$ defined by $ax+2y-3=0$. The goal is to determine $a$ such that $C_a=B$. But the only $a$ for which the line segment joining $A$ to $B$ is orthogonal to $r_a$ is $a=-4$ (as you know). However, $C_{-4}=\left(-\frac35,-\frac15\right)\ne B$.

This problem is from a youtube video, it was solved as a=5. But I am stuck that how 2 answers come out, I know math cannot be mistaken but this is a simple question and there is a contradiction.

And YouTube videos are always correct, right?! If you are not interested in human answers, what's point of posting questions here?

Axiom : "Great brother YouTube is always right", shame on the unbelievers !

of course, I didn't say youtube is always right and I am not interested in human answers, why are you attacking? On YouTube it was a math teacher who solved this question and arrived 5 but didn't mention slopes. I wrote him but he hasn't seen my message. Not necessary to be rude!

Which video is that?
